# Opening Windows NT evt files

Tags: log-files, windows

Does anyone know of a tool which allows me to open Windows NT logs. I managed to get some results by using Window's 7 Event Viewer, but for some sources, it does not have the event's description. One of which is the TimeServ

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source TimeServ cannot be found.
```

Or is there some sort of corpus containing Even IDs from different sources which I can look up?

Comment: Hmm... Open them on the server they originated from?

Comment: That would be the best way, but unfortunately, in this case, I cannot as I am not in possession of the host.

Comment: Just FYI, this article explains the reason behind the "The description ... cannot be found": http://www.eventlogblog.com/blog/2008/04/event-log-message-files-the-de.html

Comment: @LuckyLuke thanks for the page. Just read it, and understood a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few online sources/repositories of Event ID codes, yeah.  That Event, however, is informational and pretty meaningless.

[From EventID.net](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-0-source-TimeServ-eventno-1066-phase-1.htm):

> Source: TimeServ 
>   Type: Information 
>   Description: Time set (offset < .5 second)
>
> Comments: EventID.Net This event simply indicates a successful time
>   synchronization with an external time server. The time difference was
>   less than 0.5 sec., which is a normal figure for a time service that
>   works properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check that site, hopefully I will get everything that I need. Thanks again. By any chance do you know of any more good repositories, just in case this one does contain what I need? Thank you

Comment: @Goaler444  Thecnet's getting a lot better about having documentation, but I usually end up there by Googling the Event ID, but I usually [try this place first](http://kb.prismmicrosys.com/) because they have a lot of events indexed for more than just Microsoft, so it's a handy all-round place to look first.

Comment: any idea on this event please. I tried searching for it but no luck:                                                                 The description for Event ID 2003 from source Mail Service cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.